# Grafana graphing query displays 1 point but has multiple results

Tags: mysql, graph, grafana

I am currently trying to set up a query in Grafana to display a graph. I have data in the database and my query returns the results I expect, but the graph seems to only display the smallest result.

Table [test_statements]

```
| ID | ReportTime          | LapTime |
| 1  | 2018-03-29 13:02:06 | 2700    |
| 2  | 2018-03-29 13:03:06 | 2725    |
| 3  | 2018-03-29 13:04:06 | 1645    |
| 4  | 2018-03-29 13:05:06 | 2900    |
| 5  | 2018-03-29 13:06:06 | 3101    |
```

The template is structured as:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_column>) as time_sec,
  <value column> as value,
  <series name column> as metric
FROM <table name>
WHERE $__timeFilter(time_column)
ORDER BY <time_column> ASC
```

Current Query

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ReportTime) as time_sec,
  LapTime as value,
  'ReportTime' as metric
FROM test_statements
WHERE ReportTime > 0
ORDER BY ReportTime ASC
```

Here are my results:
[image]

I can see the ReportTime results are correct, but the graph is wrong.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong but a point in the correct direction would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no time scale labels on x-axis in screenshot
most likely you have `Format as` in graph editor's Metrics tab set to `Series` or `Table` instead of `Time series`.

Thus, what you see as y-axis value is the total (sum) of your individual datapoint values (approx. 7 * 2.7K) which is the default setting for series aggregation function. And x-axis is labeled with time series name(metric).

Comment: Perfect, got me on the right track.  Thanks.  I needed to set the time relative, and shift for it to display correctly.